# jQuery return like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have problems with jQuery callbacks

I try to do like this.

MainController.js

```
mapController = $.fn.mapController();

getMapController = function() {
   return mapController;
};
```

mapController.js

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.mapController = function(options) {
        let mapController = {};
        let settings = $.extend({
            save: function(data) {}
        }, options);

        mapController.openModal = function () {
             //OPEN MODAL
        }

        return: mapController
    }
}(jQuery));
```

nextController.js

```
function setPlace() {
    getMapController({
      save: function(data) {
         console.log("TEST") 
      }
    }).openMapModal();
}
```

So... I try get `mapController` in `nextController` from `getMapController` method but not workink callbacks...

How I can get callbacks in `nextController.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have introduced some confusion by naming a jQuery plugin with the same name as the object that plugin returns. Both are called `mapController`. This is not a problem on itself, but in `setPlace` you call `mapController` as if it it is the jQuery plugin (passing it options), but it is in fact the *object returned* by it (see MainController.js), which is *not* a function.

So I think you'll want to change the MainController code, and make the global `mapController` variable equal to the jQuery plugin:

```
mapController = $.fn.mapController;
              //               ^^^^^ remove parentheses.
```

Like mentioned already, make sure to remove the syntax error in the `return` statement in the MapController; it should not have a colon after it.

Comment: `this` in `$.fn.plugin` isn't `$` though. It is the jQuery object returned by `$(selector)`

Comment: Ah, yes, but apparently, it is not used like that by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`getMapController()` returns a function, you have to call it with `()`:

```
function setPlace() {
    getMapController({
      save: function(data) {
         console.log("TEST") 
      }
    })().openMapModal();
}
```

Also, you have an erroneous `:` on this line:

```
return: mapController
```

It should just be:

```
return mapController
```